# timestamp not working in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a table with one column data type as 'timestamp'. Whenever i try to do some queries on the table, even simple select statement i am getting errors.

example of a row in my column,

```
'2014-01-01 05:05:20.664592-08'
```

The statement i am trying,

```
'select * from mytable limit 10;'
```

the error i am getting is

```
'Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "051-08000"'
```

Date functions in hive like TO_DATE are also not working.If i change the data type to string, i am able to extract the date part using substring. But i need to work with timestamp.

Has anyone faced this error before? Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadoop is having trouble understanding '2014-01-01 05:05:20.664592-08' as a timestamp because of the "592-08" at the end.  You should change the datatype to string, cut off the offending portion with a string function, then cast back to timestamp:

select cast(substring(time_stamp_field,1,23) as timestamp) from mytable

Comment: should i run the above statement one time and from the next time that column works as a timestamp?

Comment: No - not unless you use that statement to populate data in a table.